# SharePoint 2010 ASP:Menu control and my own CSS based on UI and UL tags

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have generated a cool css using CSS3 generator and took its CSS style file which looks something like this.  pasted a short version though the css is long...

```
ul#css3menu,ul#css3menu ul{
margin:0;list-style:none;background-color:#C0C0C0;background-image:url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAABsCAYAAACrf9gNAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAZiS0dEAP8A/wD/oL2nkwAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9oFEgYCO8oxcpkAAABlSURBVCjPjZA7CoBADETfTnIB739GGysLIRaCsiGRbYYJ+fAyAJsACRgCrHN6XSU+j3jR8N8N68okwyLiEHC9cn6OiHAmcOvQVJC2zNULLX3KTwL2uWwjVnfZFz9aiDiFk1geyBuO2g6m9q0GQQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");background-repeat:repeat;border-width:0px;border-style:solid;border-color:#999999;-moz-border-radius:4px;-webkit-border-radius:4px;border-radius:4px;}
```

now i want to know how to incorporate this with ASP:Menu control which uses "s4-tn" class and have entirely different set of CSS...and I am using sitemap also as datasource. Can I just drop this css and reference it somewhere in asp:menu control of sharepoint and convert the menu style like css3?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

To use a different CSS classname for the menu, you'll need to edit your masterpage and modify the menu control properties. Here's the control you're looking for:

```
<SharePoint:AspMenu ID="TopNavigationMenuV4" CssClass="css3menu"...
```

More info on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476607.aspx

Comment: UrbanDude...unforunately its not working this way..even my simplerendering is set to true and inspected my ul and ui elements which are still referring the menu class of sharepoint...hummm now what?

Comment: You can modify your CSS names to overload the menu styles that SP puts out:

`div.s4-tn ul.root ul.static {...}`

Answer (score 0):

in the control do not forget to register after the master page to override the rules

```
 <SharePoint:CssRegistration name="custom.css" After="corev4.css"
```